# How to override some styles only inside another component

Tags: css-modules

I have React component with own styles. And i have to change styles for this component in another place, component etc. How i can get and use classnames?

1) My Alert component styles. (classname will change to some hash)
[alert styles pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSGJn.png)

2) My UserAuth component styles (classnames also will change to some hash)
[auth form styles pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lckLW.png)

So how to get .alert classname hash in user auth styles and use it.